# Spring Boot JPQL Query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I need to send the complete query as parameter to repository to use it in @query, how can take the parameter in @query? i used this because generate the JPQL query in the code not same every time.
`

```
@Query(/*query*/)
    List<Job> getJob(@Param("query") String query);
```

I used this way but this occurred error because transform the JPQL to SQL not I want to transform it.

```
    @Query(value="#{query}", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Job> getJob(@Param("query") String query);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a query to @Query? You can simply pass your query to entityManager.createQuery(query) and get the result. I think that will be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem by using Entity Manager another way to implement the query, in the first built interface have the header for function (getJob) like this:

```
List<Job> getJob(String query);
```

then built class implements from the interface notice need to add repository annotation in the class and write this code:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


@Override
public Object getJob(String query){
    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("from student where address=?1 and name=?2")
List<Student> findByAddressSorted(String address,String name);
```

write thecode like this in repo package.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use JPA than you need to provide Param like below. you can not pass whole query in JPA.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
List<Job> getJob(@Param("id") String id);
```

If you want to pass more params then pass as method arguments and just assign it to their respective cloumn inside a query.